# UPBGE 0.2.5 Viewport Rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I working a project in UPBGE 0.2.5. But i have a problem. My Map is Big and UPBGE Rendering all map. is there a way to do "Use Viewport Render" which is an UPBGE 0.3 feature in UPBGE 0.2.5???

Comment: i found my question answer in 0.3. but i want to do it on 0.2.5. version.  video link :https://youtu.be/JHpTFRZjl60

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my question is: my map is so big and tiring upbge system. i want to do the youtube link. if you watch, you understand the my question. system invisible the hidden places. i afraid